# Selenium element click intercepted by Grid

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape Glassdoor for job postings using Selenium. My script works for roughly 20~ postings until I get the following error:

```
ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <li class="jl...</li> is not clickable at point (219, 699). Other element would receive the click: <div class="gdGrid noPad">...</div>
```

The element that would receive the click is a grid surrounding the postings. I'm pretty sure it's not obscuring the postings. I'm not sure why it randomly can't click the next job posting. I've tried changing slp.time but nothing works. Below is the code I'm using to click on each posting.

```
 #Going through each job in this page 
    job_buttons = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("jl")  #jl for Job Listing. These are the buttons we're going to click.


    for job_button in job_buttons:  

        print("Progress: {}".format("" + str(len(jobs)) + "/" + str(num_jobs)))
        if len(jobs) >= num_jobs:
            break

        job_button.click()  #You might 
        time.sleep(5)
        collected_successfully = False

        while not collected_successfully:
            try:
                company_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="employerName"]').text
                location = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="location"]').text
                job_title = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[contains(@class, "title")]').text
                job_description = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="jobDescriptionContent desc"]').text
                collected_successfully = True
            except:
                time.sleep(5)
```

This is where I'm getting the error:

```
---> 60             job_button.click()  #You might
 61             time.sleep(5)
 62             collected_successfully = False
```

Any solutions? I'm using Chrome